# Maths Number system

Tags: math

I have a clue, why the expansion method of any value of say an x base always converts in decimal base. For example,
why if 2345 base 9 when apply the expansion method will always come to a value of base 10. Similar if we take 6577 base 8 (octal) applying expansion method i.e (6 * 8^3)+(5 * 8^2)+ (7 * 8^1)+(7 * 8^0) will systematically result to 3455 to base 10 !!! My question is why base 10 and not for example base 16....why is it systematically a decimal when using the expansion method of any base????

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing number itself and its representation for human's convenience.

We usually use decimal system as traditional one for representation of numbers as strings (literals). But number value is the same in any system

```
01111(bin) = 15(dec) = F(hex) = 17(oct) = 100010 (fibonacci) and so on
```

Comment: so how you convert octal in decimal ?

Comment: octal digits 17 denote 1*8+7, decimal digits 15 denote 1*10+5, both values are equal.

Answer (score 0):

> why is it systematically a decimal when using the expansion method of any base????

I'm gonna flip this qustion for you: Why do YOU systematically keep using decimal?

You claim that `6 * 8^3 = 3072`, I claim that `6 * 8^3 = C00`. In fact I also claim that `6 * 8^3 = 4183`. Why not `11 * 13^3 = 44242`? Or `20 * 22^10 = 11012210`? They're all correct.

You and only you chose to interpret the digits and perform arithmetic base 10.